# Преобразовать URL в URL c GET параметрами в WP

Tags: html, wordpress, url, get

Не знаю как реализовать такую фишку. Может есть плагины?
Должны быть страницы вида

```
mysite.com/services/service1/?country=<country> и
mysite.com/services/service1/?country=<country>&city=<city>

где <country> и <city> - названия стран и городов соответственно.
```

Я бы хотел получить страницы формата:

```
mysite.com/services/service1/<country>/ и
mysite.com/services/service1/<country>/<city>/
```

При чем статические страницы должны быть разными для каждой из трех ссылок внизу

```
mysite.com/services/service1/
mysite.com/services/service1/<country>/
mysite.com/services/service1/<country>/<city>/
```

Возможно ли такое? Или это ближе к извращениям?

Или в крайнем случае сделать ссылку только для mysite.com/services/service1/{country}/{city}/
Чтобы это было эквивалентно следующей ссылке (на примере России, Ростов)
mysite.com/services/service1/russia/city/?city=rostov

Comment: Про постоянные ссылки и ЧПУ читали?

Comment: я не планировал под каждую страну и город создавать отдельную страницу. Планировал использовать одну шаблонную и подставлять туда переменные из _GET

Comment: Упс, извините, не уловил. ))